# java Holder vs document-style, or why use Holders

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws, cxf

I've started to use `document-style web-services` recently.
I've learned that in this way we can have only one `part`("parameter") for input/output message, which can contain all data.
But now I've read about `Holders`, which, according to [this](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/webservice-holder/) link, is used to return multiple parameters.
Now I wonder, why should I use Holders, if I can use the document-style response, which can contain everything?
Additional info I found [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/424979/Web-Services/java/Holder-class-Web-service) still left me uncertain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've started to use document-style web-services recently. I've learned
>   that in this way we can have only one part("parameter") for
>   input/output message, which can contain all data.

You have to distinguish between `document/literal bare (or unwrapped)` and `document/literal wrapped`. While for the latter one your statement is true, it is false for the primer one. In relation to [an IBM guide for the specific type encodings](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/) you will see that `document/literal bare` can specify multiple `part` elements:

```
<types>
    <schema>
        <element name="xElement" type="xsd:int"/>
        <element name="yElement" type="xsd:float"/>
    </schema>
</types>

<message name="myMethodRequest">
    <part name="x" element="xElement"/>
    <part name="y" element="yElement"/>
</message>
<message name="empty"/>

<portType name="PT">
    <operation name="myMethod">
        <input message="myMethodRequest"/>
        <output message="empty"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
```

which results in a SOAP message:

```
<soap:envelope>
    <soap:body>
        <xElement>5</xElement>
        <yElement>5.0</yElement>
    </soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
```

One of the main disadvantages however is that you lose information on the method invoked - besides not being WS-I compliant. Therefore `document/literal wrapped` is used (which is the recommended binding-style) to bypass the limitations of `bare` binding-styles.

Further note that `document/literal wrapped` is not part of the actual WSDL spec per se:

> In document/literal style of messaging, there exists a pattern which
>   is known as wrapped-document/literal. This is just a pattern, and is
>   not a part of WSDL specification. This pattern has a mention in JSR
>   224 (JAX-WS: Java API for XML based web services).
>   ([Source](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-usagewsdl/index.html?ca=dat-))

---

@Edit: Due to your origin question and your comment regarding why you might use `Handler`s:

WSDL specifies `IN`, `OUT` and `INOUT` parameters. While the first two parameters are pretty easy to understand, the latter is a bit more tricky, as the parameter sent to the service should be returned with the modified state.

However, Java is pass by value and not pass by reference and to enable an update of the same parameter, similar to the way pass by reference works, `Handler`s can be used to "fake" a WSDL conform processing for `OUT` or `INOUT` parameters.

For a simple code example and probably better explanation please [have a look at a very similar question and its answer](http://www.coderanch.com/t/424979/Web-Services/java/Holder-class-Web-service)

Comment: thanks for explanation on the use of bare\wrapped styles, but I still don't understand why use holders, only for multiple return in bare style ws?

Comment: @secario updated my post to include more information on handler